# Sending Commands using Hping3

Tags: linux

I want to send my command to destination server.

I am using hping3. And;

```
hping3 -p 9999(running daemon and commands executing on this server) -S 127.0.0.1
```

I want to send my command. How to?

Comment: If you want you can send a text that included a txt file.

Answer (score 1):

**Hping3**

Hping3 doesn't work on layers above layer 4. If your daemon digs through packets, then you need to use **-E** to fill the TCP data. (You then use **-u** to end the communication.) But, I'm not sure you can use hping3 to make a connection to a service on a port in the way you describe.

hping3 [man page](http://www.hping.org/manpage.html)

**Connecting Alternatives**

It almost looks like you want to use netcat, or [sbd](http://packetstormsecurity.org/files/34401/sbd-1.36.tar.gz.html), which *can* send commands.

```
nc 127.0.0.1 9999
```